# Play framework datetimepicker (Eonasdan version): calendar not showing

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0

I am using the [Eonasdan date time picker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). Below is the code I have in my scala.html file.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
        <label for="starttime">Starting date:</label>
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type="text" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" class="form-control" value="2014-09-23 12:04:00" />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
            $j('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
        </script>

        </div>
    </div>
```

In my main.scala.html, I have added the following to the head section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css")" >

<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js")"></script>
```

It displays it all fine, but when I click on the Calendar glyph, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So figured it out myself.
Apparently, I needed a dependency on [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/moment.min.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Given Play as the framework have you worked out how to handle locales versus the standard Form mappings? While a date format (in and out) can be specified in the mapping -- `"myDateField" -> jodaDate("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a")` it seems to stick with the format that MomentJS decides not the one chosen via the mapping.

Comment: Just noticed `data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"` :) will try that! Thanks...

Comment: Awesome -- it Works :)